# Using the subprocess module of Python to run a program with arguments from the command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess

I am using the `call` method from the `subprocess` module of Python to run a command in the terminal

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', 'pybot', 'AdminTests', '-v', 'LOGIN URL:_mylink', '-d', '.\\results'])
```

However my call currently opens a terminal inside of itself, essentially reopening, and then dose nothing at all. Why isn't it executing the rest of my command? I have tried passing my full command as a single string, I have added the `shell` parameter to my call.. I have tried everything I can think of but nothing is making my Python script run this command in full.

Why isn't my command being ran in full?

**Edit:** The ouput of the code only opens the command line, then does nothing.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ce3C.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\r'` means Carriage Return character. You need to escape `\` to mean it literally.

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', 'pybot', 'AdminTests', '-v', 'LOGIN URL:_mylink', '-d', '.\\results'])
```

or use raw string literal:

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', 'pybot', 'AdminTests', '-v', 'LOGIN URL:_mylink', '-d', r'.\results'])
```

BTW, you can omit `.\` if it means current directory.

Comment: I'm afraid that escaping the character didn't help, but I have amended my code :(

Comment: @Leon, Or `['pybot', ...]` (no `cmd` at all)

Comment: I then get the error `[ ERROR ] Parsing '-v' failed: Data source does not exist.` which is better, but still not good. Why is trying to read an argument as a data source?

**Edit:** Both of your changes result in the same error

Comment: @Leon, I don't know about `pybot`. BTW, does the command itself work w hen you issue the command in command line, not through python ?

Comment: No, this is a pybot problem! Thank you very much for solving my issue. :)

Comment: Would you be able to tell me if I passed my variable correctly? The prior part of my Python code contains a link (named `mylink`) and I wanted to pass that into my arguments, have I done that correctly?

Comment: @Leon, Do you mean this part: `'LOGIN URL:_mylink'`?  If `mylink` is a variable, you need to concatenate it to 'LOGIN URL' string literal: `'LOGIN URL:' + mylink`